# Rules conflicts in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working with my class on a project with an htaccess file that doesn't seem to work. I have this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^ root=/myroot/

RewriteRule ^(assets|inc) - [L]
RewriteRule ^section[/]?$ %{ENV:root}section/index    
RewriteRule ^section/function/(.*)$ %{ENV:root}index.php?type=section&action=function [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)$                      %{ENV:root}index.php?type=section&action=view [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

In fact, there is three things I don't understand:

If I query an url as `/section/function/`, I should get /myroot/index.php?type=section&action=function but I get `localhost/section/function` in my browser, leading to an error. Are the url translated bidirectionnaly : myroot/index.php?type=section&action=function appearing in the browser as `/section/function/`. If I delete the last line , I get blank error page, Why so ?

Edit :

So conformally to what Olaf Dietsche said, I changed the rules into

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^ root=/myroot/

```
RewriteRule ^(assets|inc) - [L]
RewriteRule ^section[/]?$ %{ENV:root}section/index    
RewriteRule ^section/function/(.*)$ %{ENV:root}?type=section&action=function [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)$                      %{ENV:root}?type=section&action=view [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

But when I click in `<a href="section/somefunction"></a>`, I am shown a page `localhost/section/some function`. I really don't know what is going wrong....

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have

```
RewriteEngine on
```

in the .htaccess for the rules to work.

The rules *rewrite* the requests, but don't *redirect* the client. The difference between the two is

- **rewrite** send another page's content to the client, without telling the client. The client thinks, that it got the contents of the requested page.
- **redirect** send another URL to the client, causing the client to make a new request with this URL. The client knows (and displays in the browser's bar), that it received the contents of another page.

If you want to redirect the client, you must add an [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag to the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^section/function/(.*)$ %{ENV:root}index.php?type=section&action=function [R,L]
```

**Update**:

You must remove `%{ENV:root}` in front of the substitutions, because the URL is e.g. `/index.php` and not `/myroot/index.php`

```
RewriteRule ^section[/]?$ /section/index    
RewriteRule ^section/function/(.*)$ /index.php?type=section&action=function [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^section/(.*)$ /index.php?type=section&action=view [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Thank s for the explanation. Sure I have indeed RewriteEngine set to on, but it still doesn't work, why so ?

Comment: @user1611830 I tried the rules in my test environment and they work, *rewriting* `/section/function` to `/myroot/index.php`. Without error.log messages, it is difficult to tell. For example, if `/myroot/` is not a subdirectory but the *document root*, you must not prepend it to `index.php`. If it is a subdirectory, there might be no `index.php` in it. There might be some error in the PHP script itself, and so on ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to bother you. But indeed, the /myroot is the root folder so I updated my rules (see my rules) but it didn't change anything

Comment: @user1611830 Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. Please see updated answer.

Comment: I added the R redirect rule, but when I click in <a href="section/somefunction"></a>, I still get the page localhost/section/somefunction

Comment: @user1611830 Have you removed `%{ENV:root}` as in the update? Because when I test the modified rules, they call `index.php` with the arguments `type=section` and `action=view`.